# React-cookies with hooks

Tags: reactjs, cookies, redux-thunk, react-cookie

i'm using React-cookies, redux, redux-thunk and hooks.

I don't understand how to store the value of " token " as a cookie.

this is the Component `App.js`

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <CookiesProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/release/:id" component={Release} render={() => (<Login cookies={this.props.cookies} />)} />
          <Route exact path="/login" render={() => (<Login cookies={this.props.cookies} />)} component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </CookiesProvider>
  </Provider>
```

actually the `Login` component is made as hook

I receive the value of the token because of call made with this component

```
function Form({ handleSubmit, login }, props) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(undefined);
  const onSubmit = (user) => {
    login(user);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={styles.flexColumn}>

      <div className={styles.username}>
        <P>username</P>
        <Field name="username" component="input" type="text" className={styles.input} />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.password}>
        <P>password</P>
        <Field
          name="password"
          component="input"
          type="text"
          className={styles.input}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.downSection}>
        <Flex>
          <div>
            <P>
                Serve Aiuto?
            </P>
          </div>
          <a href="#">
            <div className={styles.contactLink}>
              <P>Contattaci</P>
            </div>
          </a>
        </Flex>
        <Button type="submit" text="Accedi" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

Form.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  cookies: ownProps.cookies,
}, console.log(ownProps));

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  login: loginAction,
};

const enhance = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  reduxForm({ form: 'login' }),
);

export default enhance(Form);
```

How could i store the value `token` as a cookie ? i got this value thanks to `loginAction`
I must use the library react-cookies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library for it...
Such as `react-cookie`.

You can simply do:

`import {useCookie} from 'react-cookie'`

And use cookies.

Take a look [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie)